# Mostrar datos registrados en una tabla con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Necesito mostrar los datos previamente registrados con un botón para listar dichos datos. Pero no muestra nada ni arroja error.

Script de JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnRegistrar").click(function(){
      var parametros = {
        "rut": $("#txtRut").val(),
        "nombre": $("#txtNombre").val(),
        "apellido": $("#txtApellido").val(),
        "fecha_nac": $("#txtFecha").val(),
        "fono": $("#txtFono").val(),
        "direccion": $("#txtDireccion").val()
      };

      $.ajax({
        data : parametros,
        url : 'registrar.php',
        method : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function(){
          $("#cuadro2").html("Datos ingresados");
        },
        success : function(aviso){
          $("#cuadro2").html(aviso);
          alert(aviso);
        }
      });
    });
  //});

  //$(document).ready(function(){
    $("btnListar").click(function(){
      var lista;
      $.ajax({
        data : lista,
        url : 'listar.php',
        method : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function(){
          $("#cuadro1").html("<img src='img/loading.gif' width='400px' height='400px'/>");
        },
        success : function (aviso1){
          $("#cuadro1").html(aviso1);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "clientes";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table border='1px'>
  <tr>
    <th>RUT</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
    <th>Teléfono</th>
    <th>Dirección</th>
  </tr>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>
    <td>".$row["rut"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["apellido"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["fecha_nac"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["fono"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["direccion"]."</td>
    <td><button id='delete' data-id='".$row["rut"]."'>[ X ]</button>
  </tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
} else{
  echo "Aún no hay registros";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

No entiendo por qué no arroja ninguna respuesta. Antes el código funcionaba de tal forma que al pulsar el botón de `Registrar`, se generaba automáticamente la tabla. Intenté dejar ambos métodos (`Registrar` y `Listar`) aparte, pero no funcionaba el método `Registrar`, por lo que los dejé "juntos" (fijarse en las líneas comentadas). También probé con otros navegadores como Brave, Chrome y Edge, sin obtener resultado. Espero que se entienda mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer existe un error sintaxis al momento de generar la acción click.
Para que el método se ejecute tienes que acceder con el marcador **#** para poder llegar por el id del elemento.

```
 $("#btnListar").click(function(){...
```

fuera de eso tu código se ve bien...

Comment: Efectivamente faltaba eso. Muchas gracias.